# Ищу книгу по изучению Андроид

Tags: android, retrofit

посоветуйте книгу , где очень хорошо описывается ретрофит

Answer (score 3):

[Marcus Pöhls - Retrofit: Love Working with APIs on Android](https://leanpub.com/retrofit-love-working-with-apis-on-android)